# Singleton vector different from its transpose in Julia

Tags: vector, julia, matrix-multiplication

If I define `A = [1]` I get that `A` is not equal to `A'` since they are of different types:

```
julia> A=[1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> A'
1×1 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 1

julia> A == A'
false
```

If I define another vector `B = [1, 2, 3]` and I try to do the products with `A'`and `A` I obtain the following output:

```
B=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> B*A'
3×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> B*A
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching *(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1})
...
...
```

That seems a problem of `*` operator signature that seems not to accept two `Array{Int64,1}` as operands while defining another vector `C = [4 5]` we get:

```
julia> C=[4 5]
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5

julia> B*C
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  4   5
  8  10
 12  15
```

So `*` is defined for operands of types `Array{Int64,1}` and `Array{Int64,2}` respectively. Why I cannot multiply a column vector by a singleton vector `A` but I can using `A'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this depends on how well you understand linear algebra. Julia follows the conventions of linear algebra for it's array multiplication, if you need to brush up, [wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is a good source.

It boils down to the fact that your `A` is a column vector whereas `A'` is a row vector (like `C`). Matrix multiplication is defined between `(n, k)` and `(k, m)` matrices to produce a `(n, m)` matrix. Column vectors can sometimes be thought of as `(n, 1)` matrices, so there's no well defined notion of multiplication between two column vectors.

If you want the dot product, use the `dot` function (you'll need to do `using LinearAlgebra` first). If you want an element-wise product, you can use the broadcasting notation, `u .* v`.

Comment: To me it's just strange that a singleton vector is treated as a column vector when it is clearly both a column and a row. I get that it's an implementation choice but shouldn't be better for the language to add an implementation for multiplication of column vectors (or row vectors) just to check if they are singleton and in that case returning the result, otherwise an exception?

Comment: This is a practical limitation coming from the fact that the type of a vector (`Array{T, 1}` and matrix (`Array{T, 2}`) are different. It would be bad for Julia if the type of a vector was different if it had 2 elements instead of 1. If you want to treat `A` as a `(1,1)` matrix, you can do `reshape(A, 1, 1)`.

Comment: @PrinceOfBorgo Do you also think that all empty collections should be treated the same? Is an empty numerical array the same as an empty string or an empty dictionary? Why not?

Answer (score 2):

In Julia `Vector`s are one dimensional `Array`s, while the transposition works on two dimensional matrices (`Array{T,2}` equivalent to `Matrix{T}`)

```
julia> A=[1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> collect(A')
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
```

Since transposition in Julia does not materialize the data and rather holds reference to the original I needed to use `collect` to actually see what is going on.

When using multiplication on 2-dimensional arrays you are actually using linear algebra operations.

If you want to multiply element-wise use the dot `.` operator instead:

```
julia> A .== A'
1×1 BitArray{2}:
 1
```

Note it return an `Array` rather than a single value.

If you want to multiply element-wise (rather than using linear algebra matrix multiplication) you need to vectorize again:

```
julia> B.*A
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```